# Using Arrays.asList() in Java for 2d Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having trouble figuring outa few things about the following code:

```
public final String[][] pockets = {{"STATUS CHANGERS", "RUNES", "KEY ITEMS", "TROPHIES"},
        {"POTION", "SUPER POTION", "FULL HEAL"},{"ARMOR+","ATTACK+","EXP+","HEALTH+", "DISPELL+"},
        {"QUEST ITEMS","STORY ITEMS","JOURNAL"},{TROPHIES}};


public final List<String[]> Pockets = Arrays.asList(pockets); //why couldn't I define it in the method, I wonder?
```

I am trying to figure out why I could not define the 2d Array in the `asList()` method like you might a normal Array. Also, I know there has to be a Java subclass to import or a more semantic approach.

Comment: Please clarify _like you might a normal Array_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to transform a two-dimensional array `E[][]` into a two-dimensional `List<List<E>>`, you can use the following code (look below for an explanation):

```
public final String[][] pocketArray = {{"STATUS CHANGERS", "RUNES", "KEY ITEMS", "TROPHIES"},
        {"POTION", "SUPER POTION", "FULL HEAL"}, {"ARMOR+", "ATTACK+", "EXP+", "HEALTH+", "DISPELL+"},
        {"QUEST ITEMS", "STORY ITEMS", "JOURNAL"}, {"TROPHIES"}};


public final List<List<String>> pocketList;

public Test()
{
    pocketList = new ArrayList<>(pocketArray.length);
    for (String[] pocket : pocketArray)
    {
        List<String> currentSubList = new ArrayList<>(pocket.length);
        // Nice and fast way instead of iterating over the whole array and adding the strings to the list.
        Collections.addAll(currentSubList, pocket);
        // instead, you could do something like this:
        //
        // for (String currentString : pocket)
        // {
        //     currentSubList.add(currentString);
        // }
        //
        pocketList.add(currentSubList);

        // Alternatively, you could use something like this:
        // pocketList.add(Arrays.asList(pocket));
    }
}
```

Basically, this code is creating a new `ArrayList<List<String>>` for holding all the sub-lists later.
Then it iterates over the array, and saves all the sub-arrays into the list.

---

By the way, names like `pockets` versus `Pockets` are prone to causing confusion later, I recommend you to start field names with lowercase letters and name them uniquely, by their purpose and possibly their type, like I did above.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are trying to do?
Notice the use of `new String[][]`

```
 public final List<String[]> Pockets = Arrays.asList(new String[][]{{"STATUS CHANGERS", "RUNES", "KEY ITEMS", "TROPHIES"},
        {"POTION", "SUPER POTION", "FULL HEAL"},{"ARMOR+","ATTACK+","EXP+","HEALTH+", "DISPELL+"},
        {"QUEST ITEMS","STORY ITEMS","JOURNAL"},{"TROPHIES"}});
```

PS: `Pockets` is not a standard naming convention, I suggest `pocketList`

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to figure out why I could not define the 2d Array in the asList() method like you might a normal Array.

We cannot answer why what you tried did not work when you do not tell us what you tried.  I suppose what you really want to know, however, is how to generate a `List<String[]>` via `Arrays.asList()` by passing the individual elements, instead of first constructing a 2D array.  That would be this:

```
public final List<String[]> pockets = Arrays.asList(
        new String[]{"STATUS CHANGERS", "RUNES", "KEY ITEMS", "TROPHIES"},
        new String[]{"POTION", "SUPER POTION", "FULL HEAL"},
        new String[]{"ARMOR+","ATTACK+","EXP+","HEALTH+", "DISPELL+"},
        new String[]{"QUEST ITEMS","STORY ITEMS","JOURNAL"},
        new String[]{"TROPHIES"}
    );
```

Note in particular that Java has no array literals, only array *initializers* (which can be associated with array declarations), and array *constructors*, such as in the above code.  I speculate that in your attempt(s), you omitted the `new String[]` bits that make those constructors.  Those bits are necessary to specify the element type of the arrays, if for no other reason.

> Also, I know there has to be a Java subclass to import or a more semantic approach.

I've no idea what you mean.  You're already using class `java.util.Array` to perform the construction, and you're building a `java.util.List`.  I guess for most purposes I'd recommend using a `List` of `List`s (`List<List<String>>`) and avoiding arrays altogether, but I can't be sure whether that would be suitable for your purposes.